# iOS where to put custom cell design? awakeFromNib or cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitableview, custom-cell

So, basically i made a custom cell from a nib, wish i apply a little custom design, like colors and shadows.

I found two ways of applying the styling:

#### awakeFromNib():

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    //Container Card Style
    self.container.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    self.container.setDropShadow(UIColor.blackColor(), opacity: 0.20, xOffset: 1.5, yOffset: 2.0, radius: 1.8)

    //Rounded thumbnail
    self.thumb_image.setRoundedShape()
    self.thumb_image.backgroundColor = UIColor.customGreyTableBackground()

    //Cell
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.customGreyTableBackground()
    self.selectionStyle = .None
}
```

#### cellForRowAtIndexPath: (inside the tableView wish will show the cell)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //get cell type
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchResultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchResultCell

    //Container Card Style
    cell.container.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    cell.container.setDropShadow(UIColor.blackColor(), opacity: 0.20, xOffset: 1.5, yOffset: 2.0, radius: 1.8)

    //Rounded thumbnail
    cell.thumb_image.setRoundedShape()
    cell.thumb_image.backgroundColor = UIColor.customGreyTableBackground()

    //Cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.customGreyTableBackground()
    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    //cell data
    if(!data.isEmpty){
        cell.name_label.text = data[indexPath.row].name
        cell.thumb_url = data[indexPath.row].thumb_url
    }

    return cell
}
```

In terms of performance, wish one will be better? I've noticed that in a **awakeFromNib()** the design only does it once, so this is the better one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mentioned awakeFromNib is only called once (when the cell is instantiated), if its setting stuff like background colors and stuff like that that wont change then its ok to do it there, cell customization (the data that the cell is showing) should be done during cellForRowAtIndexPath, so you should not check if the data is empty there rather, give it the data everytime the cell is returned, this will allow you to reuse cells and set the data as needed

Hope this helps

Daniel

Comment: Thanks Daniel, i thought this was the right think to do, but since people say to put the data at cellForRowAtIndexPath, i thought why not also the design.. so made this question here to clear everything out of my mind :)