# Best practice for re-rendering a subview on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass which has a custom subview which is created through code. Now the problem is I'm trying to make the scrolling of the UITableView **less jumpy**.

Here's how this is setup.

1. `CustomSubview` is a `UIView` created through code
2. `BasePostCell` is a `UITableViewCell` is a `UITableViewCell` subclass that is used as a base for some other cells
3. `UserPostCell`, `TextPostCell`, and `DiscussionPostCell` are `BasePostCell` subclasses which are made using `xib`s and so far since I don't know if it is possible to somehow inherit an xib to another xib I just used `viewWithTag` and `awakeFromNib` to connect the subviews to their respective variables, which you will see on the sample code below
4. All of these are setup with `NSLayoutConstraints` which from what I've read/researched is significantly slower than if I create the view's through code and then just manually calculate the height, and width of each cell. I would if I could but right now I don't have the luxury of doing so because there are about 20+ different cells in the real code base. (this is just a sample code)

The class I want to change somehow is either `CustomSubview` or `BasePostCell`; or if there is a better way to do this please tell me.

Here's my code

The Model

```
class Post {
    var type: PostType = .text
    var text: String = ""
    var title: String = ""
    var displayPhoto: String?

    // ... there are other attributes here

    enum PostType {
        case text, user, discussion
    }
}
```

The Base Classes

```
class CustomSubview: UIView {
    lazy var likeButton: UIButton = { 
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(face: .helveticaNeue, style: .regular, size: 14) // this is a helper function of mine
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .selected)
        return button
    }()

    // The rest are more or less the same as how likeButton is created
    // the most important part is `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`
    // should be set to true since I use `NSLayoutConstraints`
    lazy var commentButton: UIButton = { ... }() 
    lazy var shareButton: UIButton = { ... }()
    lazy var followButton: UIButton = { ... }()
    lazy var answerButton: UIButton = { ... }()

    func configure(withType type: PostType) {

        // I don't know if this is the right way to do this
        self.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

        switch type {
        case .text:
            [ self.likeButton, self.commentButton, self.shareButton ].forEach { self.addSubview($0) }

            // constraints code block
            // code goes something like this
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[btnLike(==btnComment)]-0-[btnComment]-0-[btnShare(==btnComment)]-0-|",
                options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
                metrics: nil,
                views: ["btnLike": self.likeButton,
                        "btnComment": self.commentButton,
                        "btnShare": self.shareButton]))

        case .user:
            [ self.followButton, self.shareButton ].forEach { self.addSubview($0) }

            // insert more constraints code block here
        case .discussion:
            [ self.answerButton, self.commentButton, self.shareButton ].forEach { self.addSubview($0) }

            // insert more constraints code block here
        }
    }
}

class BasePostCell: UITableViewCell {

    // ... there are other subviews but
    // only this view is modularly created
    var customSubview: CustomSubview?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.customSubview = self.viewWithTag(990) as? CustomSubview
    }

    func configure(withPost post: Post) {
        self.customSubview?.configure(withType: post.type)
    }
}
```

The subclasses of the BasePostCell

```
class UserPostCell: BasePostCell {
    var imgDisplayPhoto: UIImageView?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.imgDisplayPhoto = self.viewWithTag(0) as? UIImageView
    }

    override func configure(withPost post: Post) {
        super.configure(withPost: post)
        self.imgDisplayPhoto?.image = post.image
    }
}

class TextPostCell: BasePostCell {
    var lblContent: UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.lblContent = self.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
    }

    override func configure(withPost post: Post) {
        super.configure(withPost: post)
        self.lblContent?.text = post.text
    }
}

class DiscussionPostCell: BasePostCell {
    var lblContent: UILabel?
    var lblDiscussionTitle: UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.lblContent = self.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
        self.lblDiscussionTitle = self.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel
    }

    override func configure(withPost post: Post) {
        super.configure(withPost: post)
        self.lblContent?.text = post.text
        self.lblDiscussionTitle?.text = post.title
    }
}
```

And finally the implementation on a `SampleViewController`

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var posts: [Post] = []
    var heightForPost: [IndexPath: CGFloat] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // let's just say I initialized the posts
        self.posts = <SomePostsArrayHere>

        // ... register nib to tableview codes here.

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // ... other implementations
}

// Here is the delegate and dataSource
extension SomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row]

        var postCell: BasePostCell

        switch post.type {
        case .text:
            postCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextPostCell", for: indexPath) as! TextPostCell
        case .user:
            postCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserPostCell", for: indexPath) as! UserPostCell
        case .discussion:
            postCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DiscussionPostCell", for: indexPath) as! DiscussionPostCell
        }

        postCell.configure(withPost: post)

        return postCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.heightForPost[IndexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.heightForPost[indexPath] ?? UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 300
    }
}
```

Comment: Use time profiler to detect what actually causes lagging.. otherwise you'll risk optimizing things that are not really your problem

Comment: @MilanNosáľ ok I'll do that, but still the `configure` of my `CustomView` still looks like a pretty bad implementation, since everytime the cell appears it gets called.

Comment: OK, I see what might be the problem.. still I would check the profiler

Comment: I don't think you need a BasePostCell here, to make it simpler just configure your custom view before setting up each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already suggested using time profiler to identify the problem code, but still I see one no-no in your code.

In configuring your cells, you always call `configure(withType type: PostType)` on your `CustomSubview`. And there, you remove the subviews and "rebuild" them. That's not something you should be doing in reusable cells - you don't want to touch their view hierarchy, all you want to do is to change their contents, e.g., change the text in a label, change an image in an imageView, etc. Otherwise you are not using the full power of reusable cells.

Just change the `BaseClass` to configure the subviews hierarchy just once, and then in `cellForRowAt` set just the contents of subviews:

```
class BasePostCell: UITableViewCell {

     // ... there are other subviews but
    // only this view is modularly created
    var customSubview: CustomSubview?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.customSubview = self.viewWithTag(990) as? CustomSubview
    }

    func configure(withPost post: Post) {
        // don't reconfigure the customView view hierarchy here, it gets called everytime cellForRowAt is called
    }
}


class UserPostCell: BasePostCell {
    var imgDisplayPhoto: UIImageView?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // subviews setup just once here, because for the UserPostCell
        // the type of the post will never change
        self.customSubview?.configure(withType: .user)

        self.imgDisplayPhoto = self.viewWithTag(0) as? UIImageView
    }

    override func configure(withPost post: Post) {
        super.configure(withPost: post)
        self.imgDisplayPhoto?.image = post.image
    }
}

class TextPostCell: BasePostCell {
    var lblContent: UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.customSubview?.configure(withType: .text)

        self.lblContent = self.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
    }

    override func configure(withPost post: Post) {
        super.configure(withPost: post)
        self.lblContent?.text = post.text
    }
}

class DiscussionPostCell: BasePostCell {
    var lblContent: UILabel?
    var lblDiscussionTitle: UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.customSubview?.configure(withType: .discussion)

        self.lblContent = self.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
        self.lblDiscussionTitle = self.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel
    }

    override func configure(withPost post: Post) {
        super.configure(withPost: post)
        self.lblContent?.text = post.text
        self.lblDiscussionTitle?.text = post.title
    }
}
```

Comment: One question though. If I call `self.customSubview?.configure(withType: <TYPE>)` on `awakeFromNib` will `configure(withPost post: Post)` be called first on `cellForRow` before `awakeFromNib` life cycle speaking?

Comment: @ZonilyJame while I always do everything in code, I believe that `awakeFromNib` will be always called before `cellForRowAt` (in `dequeueReusableCell`), so I stand by my answer :). One similar question on SO recommends basically the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161109/ios-where-to-put-custom-cell-design-awakefromnib-or-cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: Yeah, I actually did what you suggested. It seems to be faster by a few ms now.